# Simple AS3 1046 and 1180 errors

Tags: actionscript-3

I am getting a 1180 and 1046 compiler error when working with AS3.
I am trying to create a thing that places a car on the stage.  Very simple, but I can't get it to work.
I have a movie clip symbol named `Car`, with an AS linkage `MyCar3`. 
Here is my code:

```
var MyCar3:Car = new Car();
stage.addChild(MyCar3);

MyCar3.x = 500;
MyCar3.y = 350;
```

My compiler says

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Car.

and

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Car.

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
var car:MovieClip = new MyCar3();
stage.addChild(car);
car.x = 500;
car.y = 350;
```

Remember that AS linkange is actual name of the class that generates the object that you can attach to the screen.

Comment: I think he mixed up between symbol name `Car` and linkage name `MyCar3`, but he should still be able to use `var car:MyCar3 = new MyCar3();`

Comment: That is what I suggested. But var car:MyCar3 and var car:MovieClip are equally good as long as he modifies only x,y properties.